# refreshing StubHub API tokens?

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0

We are trying to refresh a previously working application's refresh tokens as per **stub-hub**'s [developers docs](https://developer.stubhub.com/docs/authentication/token-expiration) with the following commands (where `<whatever>` are account specific placeholders).

```bash
ENCRYPTED_ACCT=$(echo -n "<client-id>:<client-secret>" | base64);

curl -X POST "https://account.stubhub.com/oauth2/token" \
  -u "${ENCRYPTED_ACCT}" --basic \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d "grant_type=refresh_token" \
  -d "refresh_token=<PREV_REFRESH_TOKEN>" \
  --data-urlencode "scope=read:events";
```

In the past we've followed a similar flow (api changed since). But now with the recommended procedure the endpoint is failing due to invalid credentials for the `ENCRYPTED_ACCT`. Can anyone post a functioning workflow to refresh tokens of an existing account?

Comment: hey do you know from where client id and client secret is generated ?

Comment: These should be available from your StubHub developer account.

Comment: Not available there. They have changed something in their API which makes it difficult to access the client ID and secret.